# Thirteen properties of Euclidean Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm reading "Taxicab Geometry: Adventure in Non-Euclidean Geometry" by Eugene F Krause where he mentioned:

> A geometry is called Euclidean if it satisfies the following thirteen
> properties:
>
> 1. Given any two points there is exactly one line containing them.
> 2. Every line contains at least two points, P contains at least 3 non-collinear points.
> 3. The distance between two points is a non-negative number and is zero only if the two points coincide.
> 4. The distance from A to B equals the distance from B to A.
> 5. The distance function satisfies the triangle inequality property.
> 6. Given any line, there exists a one-to-one and onto function that acts as a ruler for all pairs of points A, B on the line.
> 7. Each line divides the space into two convex half-planes.
> 8. The angle measurement function assigns to each angle a real number between 0 and 180.
> 9. Given a ray ($\overrightarrow{AB}$) on the edge of a half-plane and given a real number r between 0 and 180, there is exactly one ray extending from A
>    into the half-plane with the angle measure of r.
> 10. The angle addition property.
> 11. Two angles forming a straight angle sum to 180.
> 12. The side-angle-side congruence holds for triangles.
> 13. The parallel postulate: Given a point A not on a line l, there is exactly one line through A parallel to l.

May I ask, is there a name for such 13 properties?

Comment: Perhaps '*axiom system*'? Or what do you mean?

Comment: The Euclidean axioms?

Comment: Vague. What is P (#2)? What does "acts as a ruler" mean (#6)? What is a half-plane (#7 & #9) and what does "convex" mean (#7)?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet indeed there are more to fill in, P is the plane, convexity is defined in the book

Comment: Gilbert's axioms

Comment: @SenZen but [Euclide’s original version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry#Axioms) only has 5 axioms, [Hilbert’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) has 21, who do you mean by Gilbert?